# How to scale out selenium test suites across different servers

Tags: selenium

I was wondering how people scale out selenium tests. IE I have 4 suites and instead of running all them on just one server I want them to be spread out over multiple servers to decrease the time it takes to run. I'm wondering if anyone has a solution where I can have some kind of database to track which tests have run for that day and just pick up the ones that have not run and run through those, Then at the end use the selenium tools to build the master report for the tests.

I know there is a low tech solution of just tracking which tests each server should run but I'd like to be able to either autoscale my testing servers, or at least not have to manually track which tests each server has run.

I'm really hoping this does exist but if not I think I may have to start a new open source project.

Answer (score 0):

[selenium grid](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2) might be what your looking for. It allows you to run browsers on multiple machines. It works a little differently than what you are describing. A client runs the tests and makes requests to the grid which runs the browsers. So the test results are only produced on the client so there is no need to aggregate test reports from the multiple machines.